# WPF Application Incorporating WinAPI (Win8) components

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi, windows-8.1

I have a WPF application which utilizes a handwriting control.

By using an

```
<InkCanvas></InkCanvas>
```

In my XAML, I was able to get the user's strokes, and turn them into text using the InkAnalysis class.  However, this is strictly 32bit, and my requirements dictate a 64bit build.

Unable to find a 64bit compatible library, I looked into upgrading to .NET 4.5 and utilizing the Windows8 classes which are available to desktop apps (by also adding
    <TargetPlatformVersion>8.1</TargetPlatformVersion> to the csproj file so that I could add the 'Windows' namespace references).  Luckily, Windows.UI.Input.Inking is.

However, when I add the reference to Windows.UI.Input.Inking, I get a build error which states:

```
Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Foundation.Metadata.PlatformAttribute'. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent Windows Runtime assemblies must be resolved on demand through the ReflectionOnlyNamespaceResolve event.'
```

I have looked into the:

```
Windows.Foundation.Metadata.PlatformAttribute
```

And it seems to want an enum member, either:

```
Windows.Foundation.Metadata.Platform.Windows
```

or

```
Windows.Foundation.Metadata.Platform.WindowsPhone
```

This is a desktop application, so I would obviously choose to target Platform.Windows, but cannot figure out how to tell the compiler this.

How can I incorporate this Windows.UI.Input.Inking class into my WPF application?  My end goal is simply to convert strokes from the inkcanvas into text, in a 64 bit environment.

Comment: Take a look at this post:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/10/29/how-to-use-specific-winrt-api-from-desktop-apps-capturing-a-photo-using-your-webcam-into-a-wpf-app.aspx. Note that these APIs are only available for Windows 8, so even you manage to get this working, your desktop app will not work in other OSes.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to your problem ? Before I was using WinRT API from desktop app by following some tutorials. But now, when I change the <TargetPlatformVersion> to 8.1 I have the same problem as you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that I was receiving this error due to the reference added to the:

`Windows.UI.Input.Inking`

library.  It seems that the correct way to add reference to Windows 8/8.1 WinAPI components (from a non WinAPI application) is the following:

1. Add `<TargetPlatformVersion>8.1</TargetPlatformVersion>` to the csproj file
2. Add reference to the `Windows` library (this is the key - adding the specific lib, in this case, `Windows.UI.Input.Inking`, causes the build error)
3. Add the more specific (ex: `Windows.UI.Input.Inking`) reference in the actual file where the API is required

I am working on creating a NuGet package which will edit the csproj file, and add the `Windows` reference.  I'll update this if/when it is completed.

Comment: Any news about your NuGet package?