# Change Windows 8.1 lock screen image via WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I'm trying to change Windows 8.1 (desktop) lock screen image from WPF application.

I've found [solution with Windows SDK approach](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Personalization-App-sample-9ebfe147), but it uses runtime application as example (actually, all information I've found was regarding to WinRT apps). But I don't want to use WinRT - all I want is to use [LockScreen class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.lockscreen.aspx) in plain old WPF.

After all I have managed to do this in the WPF app several times. This included:

1) manually adding `<TargetPlatformVersion/>8.1</TargetPlatformVersion>` into .csproj as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103561/wpf-application-incorporating-winapi-win8-components);

2) adding references to `Windows` and `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime` as suggested ibid;

3) following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492434/change-windows-lock-screen-background-image-in-c-sharp) to change lock screen background

Then I've faced the problem with platform - application does what it should only with x64 platform (not anyCPU). And not each time (I could not determine consistency yet).

Any way I think that I am over-complicating the solution. Does anyone have other suggestions? Is there any other simpler/cleaner way to change Windows 8.1 lock screen image via WPF application?